# Handlebars is adding a space between my divs?

Tags: jquery, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwl707/mVwYM/2/)

I have a selection of divs that are created with handlebars,( link above ) , In my styling for the divs there are no margins or padding yet when they are rendered with handlebars I have a gap between the divs, I dont want them there, any advice please?

```
     <div id='vehicles' class='wrapper'>
         <div class='divd'>&nbsp</div>
            {{#each this}}
               <div id='{{group}}' title='Driver Details' class='divd {{group}}' >
               {{trailer}} 
               </div>
            {{/each}}
         </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `inline-block` uses the whitespace around the `div`s (this has nothing to to with Handlebars).

---

Just set the parent element's `font-size` to 0, then set the `font-size` of the `div`s directly:

```
.wrapper {
    font-size: 0;
}

.divd { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;   
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fz2Hv/

Answer (score 1):

Its because of `display:inline-block`. You need to eliminate the space between the HTML from div to div:

```
</div><div id="NewDiv">
```

Instead of

```
</div>
<div id="NewDiv">
```

Crude example, but you get what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

Your styles ask for each `.divd` to be `display: inline-block`. This makes them behave with respect to whitespace around the tag in the same fashion as regular inline elements (e.g., plain text). Just like how in plain text you have spaces in the markup lead to spaces on the page, you get that here to. One possible way to fix this is to set `font-size: 0` on the parent, which will make that space zero on the parent container. You'd have to add back a `font-size` in the children though.

http://jsfiddle.net/F6JE7/